# Is there a way to tell the Android Status Bar panel to close?

Tags: android, statusbar

I have an application which exhibits two different behaviors, possible related to
Android 2.2 vs. Android 2.1 update 1.

The application uses the proximity sensor to determine when the phone is "near"
the ear.  If a "near" condition is detected, I get the applications window and
set the LayoutParams to FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE and FLAG_FULLSCREEN.  In general, this
has the desired effect of preventing accidental screen touches by the ear from
causing any unwanted action.  However...

With my Android V2.2 phones:  If I am in the process of sliding open the Status
Bar at the time the proximity sensor detects a "near" condition, the Status Bar
immediately closes and all is good.

With my Android V2.1 phones:  If I have the Status Bar partially open, detect a
"near" condition, and then simultaneously (more or less) revert to a "far" 
condition while releasing the Status Bar, the Status Bar is left in a partially
opened state.  Meanwhile, part of my application remains visible, but not
touchable.  I can simulate this at will with 2.1 phones, but can not do so
at all with 2.2 phones.

My questions:

1)  Does anyone know why this behavior is different, and if it is indeed related
    to different Android versions?

2)  Is there a way that an application (such as mine!) can detect if the Status
    Bar is opened, or in the process of sliding open, and tell it to close?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457730/preventing-status-bar-expansion