# Preventing status bar expansion

Tags: android, statusbar, lockscreen

Is there anyway to prevent users from sliding the status bar (expand) or collapsing back?

I'm trying out a lockscreen replacement and seems like it's a must-have feature. Is there any possible way to do it without requiring root privileges?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this?

Comment: I'm building a lockscreen alternative. So, being able to slide your notifications bar down is not a feature of a lockscreen.

Comment: SOLUTION :> http://stackoverflow.com/a/25308654/2219600

Comment: Google itself gives you example code: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score 20):

You can actually prevent the status bar from expanding, without rooting phone.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284233/prevent-status-bar-for-appearing-android-modified).  This draws a window the height of the status bar and consumes all touch events.

Call the following code just after onCreate().

```
public static void preventStatusBarExpansion(Context context) {
    WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

    Activity activity = (Activity)context;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

    // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

    // Draws over status bar
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels
    int resId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    int result = 0;
    if (resId > 0) {
        result = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
    }

    localLayoutParams.height = result;

    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(context);

    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
}

public static class customViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    public customViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.v("customViewGroup", "**********Intercepted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround, but the top area is disabled for click events, can you please suggest anything for that?

Comment: @SamvelKartashyan - edited answer to make the window only draw over status bar.  All other events should now be clickable.

Comment: @tsiro, yes, definitely.

Comment: how to restore the status bar expansion again ?

Comment: This solution was working great but after changing the target sdk level to 26 (from 23) I'm getting the error " android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@632ab9c -- permission denied for window type 2010". The app already has "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />" Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Thanks for such great solution. I was looking to disable it. Still could not find a solution. And finally, I found yours solution and it works perfect. For that BadTokenException, we need to request permission for "Display overlay" in code. After that all are working fine. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 18):

Short answer: this is impossible!

Now should you be interested to know why this is impossible:

There are two permissions for manipulating the system status bar, [EXPAND_STATUS_BAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#EXPAND_STATUS_BAR) and [STATUS_BAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#STATUS_BAR). The former can be requested by any application, but the later is reserved for applications signed with the platform signature (system applications, not third-party). It *is possible* to expand/ collapse the system status bar (see ["How to open or expand status bar through intent?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021310/how-to-open-or-expand-status-bar-through-intent)) but note that reflection is required because the [StatusBarManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/app/StatusBarManager.java?av=f) class is not part of the SDK. The disable method, which is used by the Android dialer to prevent the status bar from being expanded, cannot be accessed by an application without the aforementioned STATUS_BAR permission.

Sources: personal experience :-)

Comment: Thanks @farble1670 I am certain that it is correct. Without root/ building an app in /system/app you cannot call the StatusBarMananger.disable() method without getting a SecurityException.

Answer (score 15):

**First of all**, it's impossible to modify the Status Bar if your app is not signed with the phone's rom certified, if you try to modify it you'll get an Security Exception.

**Update**: In new APIs the method is "collapsePanels" instead of "collapse".

The only way I've found after several hours of work is by overriding the "onWindowFocusChanged" method of the activity and when it loses the focus (maybe the user has touched the notifications bar), force to collapse the StatusBar, here is the code (working on a Defy+ 2.3.5).

You need to declare the following permission on the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
```

And override the following method:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
        try
        {
           if(!hasFocus)
           {
                Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16 ? "collapsePanels" : "collapse");
                collapse.setAccessible(true);
                collapse.invoke(service);
           }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
}
```

**Update**: You will have to use your own custom Alert Dialog by overriding it their onWindowFocusChanged method too, because Alert Dialogs have their own focus.

Comment: This method is such a hack, it lets the user expand the status bar to a certain extent then pulls it back up. Its better to just cover the status bar with a View that consumes all onTouchEvents.

Comment: I tried to use that workaround, but I couldn't. Could you tell us how did you make it?

Comment: Grandland Chew's answer does exactly what you want, you overlay the status bar and accept all touch input.

Comment: I've used a similar code but it does not work, what API are you using?

Comment: These is no "API" for disabling status bar expansion that non-system apps can use. Grandland's method works just fine, placing a window of the status bar that consumes touch events.

Comment: It works just fine on ANY API level 4 and up. You use the WindowManager class which has NOT changed its fundamental implementation in a while.

Comment: It works very well, but you forgot to say that it requires <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />

Comment: Not working on my android 4.2.2 galaxy tab 8", throwing exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: collapse []

Comment: Also not working for on Tab3 with 4.2.2. I do not receive any errors but nothing happens. Status expands as normal and do not collapse. Any thoughts?

Comment: throwing exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: collapse

Comment: If I have the ROM certificate signed APK then How can we Disable the Notification Panel with Quick Settings also on Lock Screen?

Comment: Great answer. What about bottom navigation bar?

Answer (score 13):

This actually can be done via a little hack that I accidentally discovered, but requires the permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`:

What you do is add a view the exact size of the status bar directly to the WindowManager with the certain parameters that covers the status bar and prevents it from receiving touch events:

```
View disableStatusBarView = new View(context);

WindowManager.LayoutParams handleParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    <height of the status bar>,
    // This allows the view to be displayed over the status bar
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
    // this is to keep button presses going to the background window
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
    // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
    // Draws over status bar
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

handleParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
context.getWindow().addView(disableStatusBarView, handleParams);
```

This will basically create a transparent view over the status bar that will receive all the touch events and block the events from reaching the status bar and therefore prevents it from being expanded.

NOTE: This code is untested, but the concept works.

Comment: This works, I can confirm. With a few tweaks, call to system resources to retrieve the exact height, and default fallbacks this work like a charm.

Comment: Some working code would be VERY VERY helpful! As well, eclipse is telling me to use addContentView instead of addView?

Comment: this does not seems to be working for me at the moment; while I can draw over the status bar area I can not prevent the status bar expansion nor capture touch events

Comment: @ademar: Things might have have changed slightly in Jelly Bean, is that what you're testing on?

Comment: @Tom I tried on a tablet and doesn't work. Anyone get success on tablet?

Comment: @Derzu the status bar is on the bottom for tablets, did you try Gravity.BOTTOM?

Comment: @Tom, yes, I tried with the Gravity.BOTTOM, but still does not work.

Comment: @Derzu You CANNOT draw over the tablet "system bar" at the bottom of the screen. This is for security reasons, concerns similar to drawing over the navigation bar. Doing this prevents the user from being able to exit an app, an obvious concern with malicious apps.

Comment: @Tom It is not for a malicious app, it is for a kiosk mode app.

Comment: @Derzu I didn't mean to imply that it was, but without special permissions (your app living in /system/app and having system permissions) this cannot be done.

Comment: This does not work for me also. I am trying on a Jelly Bean device and it gives me a force close. Too bad, I thought it was a good idea.

Comment: It says: "Unable to add window -- Permission denied for this window type"

Comment: This does not work for me either, it does not cover the status bar

Comment: that's not a hack. it's known and intented. Thus it is not wanted.

Comment: For me its cover top but dont prevent action of slidedown from status bar. (API 23, Moto X)

Comment: This will only work if your app is running as a system process.  Also TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT was deprecated in API level 26.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the solutions mentioned by ***GrantLand*** and ***PoOk*** but both didn't work in my case. Though, Another solution [Clear/Hide Recent Tasks List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890415/android-how-to-clear-the-recent-task-list-which-could-get-from-home-button-in-m) did the trick for me. I am writing a launcher app for which I had to disable a recent applications menu so user cannot open a locked app from it. Also, I had to prevent against notification bar expansion and this trick made me achieve both. Override **OnWindowFocusChanged** method in your activity and check if this is what u wanted.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

    if(!hasFocus) {
        Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me in my lockscreen app.

Comment: The better solution is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371802/permanently-hide-android-status-bar

Comment: I tested the code on my nexus 5x 8.0, and found It failed to stop status bar from expanding, could you test it and add another solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For a lockscreen Why don't you just use the following in your main activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
}
```

If the user doesn't have a secure lockscreen set the app will let the user pull the status bar down and open activities but that doesn't matter as the user obviously doesn't want a secure screen anyway.

If the user does have a secure locksreen set then the app will show the status bar but will not allow interactions with it. This is because the phone is still actually locked and only your activity is allowed to operate until the user unlocks the phone. Also closing your app in anyway will open the standard secure lockscreen. All this is highly desirable because you don't have to spend all that time coding secure features that you can't guarantee will be as secure as the stock ones.

If you really don't want the user to be able to interact with the status bar, maybe you can leave out the flag `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` call. Then just before you are about to unlock the phone set the flag like I showed in the first block. I don't know if this last part works but it's worth a try.

Hope that helps

Comment: Won't work as described Android L and above. FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED clears FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD. Known bug.

Comment: And your answer unfortunatelly doesnt 'answer' the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it does not work. using `FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN` prevents you from catching any touch events.

And BTW:
to add a view to the window use the window manager:

```
WindowManager winMgr = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
winMgr.addView(disableStatusBar, handleParams);
```

Comment: You sure? I'm using it for same purpose and it is not.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is collapse the status bar in a loop, so when user tries to expand it, it automatically will collapse, here is the code, just add it in your MainActivity.java file:

```java
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") Object service = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                Method collapse = statusBarManager.getMethod(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16 ? "collapsePanels" : "collapse");
                collapse.setAccessible(true);
                collapse.invoke(service);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // handle exception
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
```

Comment: This is not working on Android 13. I guess it won't work on Android 12 as well. throws SecurityException saying that this user does not have STATUS_BAR permission

Comment: @mohammadrezasarsarabi In the AndroidManifest.xml add this permission: ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>```

Comment: that does not help. it's only good for expanding not collapsing. Still getting SecurityException

Answer (score -4):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: This will make the app fullscreen and hence hide the status bar. I do not want this as this will bring more work for me by having to implement by own status bar.

Comment: status bar can be still made visible and thus can be shown even in full screen...