# Android status bar permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I want to enable android.permissions.STATUS_BAR in my app. Is it possible to do so, given that I am targeting possibly non-rooted phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, `android.persmissions.STATUS_BAR` is a System persmission and can't be used.

In android terms it falls under `signatureOrSystem` permission. The meaning is (taken from [Android Manifest DOCS](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html))...

`A permission that the system grants only to applications that are in the Android system image or that are signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. Please avoid using this option, as the signature protection level should be sufficient for most needs and works regardless of exactly where applications are installed. The "signatureOrSystem" permission is used for certain special situations where multiple vendors have applications built into a system image and need to share specific features explicitly because they are being built together.`

Have a look at the following links as well. They might help you find a workaround...

[How to disable statusbar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175250/how-to-disable-statusbar-in-android)
[Why are these permissions being refused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476600/why-are-these-permissions-being-refused)
[Preventing status bar expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457730/preventing-status-bar-expansion/10380535)

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case. My own research seems to correspond to this as well.. :/ Thanks anyway ya.