# Android Kiosk Mode app. Block Notification bar and recent apps button

Tags: android, android-intent, kiosk-mode

I'm developing Kiosk mode, HOME launcher application. There are some glitches that I can't fix.

1. My application hides notification bar, but then user launches any granted application, notification bar appears. Is any posibility to prevent user using notification bar. There is such [interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html) but as seems it is not right soliution. Am I wrong?
2. I can manage toogling recent apps window on my application activity, but like notification bar, then user enters to any granted application I'cant control recent apps button.

Is any way to prevent any application start by intent? I'm thinking about [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) but due to low documentation I don't know can I achieve my goal.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hi foo, if you have found any way please let me know. What I have tried is, created a service which checks for current running task. If it is not what I want then I start my app again.

Comment: As seems to me the best way to prevent of using any application is starting other application if current running application isn't granted. In my case I use deamon `TimerTask` running at fixed time periods. It's much simpler than services.

Comment: If you want to collapse notificationbar at any point you can use java reflection. This is [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457730/preventing-status-bar-expansion). In my case I appended my `TimerTask` to try to collapse notification by each second.