# How to disable status bar click and pull down in Android?

Tags: android

How can I disable a status bar click and pull down in Android? I have tried many things but this is not working.

Comment: what have you tried yet ? posting your efforts might get you a better answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing status bar expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457730/preventing-status-bar-expansion)

Comment: i just want to make user to stop pulling status bar. how is it possible?

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        i have applied this code but its not working

Comment: @NazimaKauserMMF - have you found anything that's working?

Answer (score 23):

In my opinion, there are 2 options:

OPTION 1: You can lay a window over the status bar to disable any touch or pulling down.

OPTION 2: You can also override the OnWindowFocusChanged() method to close the notification panel immediately after it shows up.

How to:

OPTION 1: Define the following method(preventStatusBarExpansion) and class(CustomViewGroup) in your activity.

```
public static void preventStatusBarExpansion(Context context) {
    WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

    Activity activity = (Activity)context;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

    // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

    // Draws over status bar
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int resId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    int result = 0;
    if (resId > 0) {
        result = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
    }

    localLayoutParams.height = result;

    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(context);

    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
}

public static class customViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    public customViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.v("customViewGroup", "**********Intercepted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And call the preventStatusBarExpansion method in the onCreate method of the activity. Done!

OPTION 2: First, add the following permission to the Androidmanifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Second, define the following class-scope variables in your activity:

```
// To keep track of activity's window focus
boolean currentFocus;

// To keep track of activity's foreground/background status
boolean isPaused;

Handler collapseNotificationHandler;
```

Third, override onWindowFocusChanged(boolean):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    currentFocus = hasFocus;

    if (!hasFocus) {

        // Method that handles loss of window focus
        collapseNow();
    }
}
```

Forth, define the collapseNow(); method:

```
public void collapseNow() {

    // Initialize 'collapseNotificationHandler'
    if (collapseNotificationHandler == null) {
        collapseNotificationHandler = new Handler();
    }

    // If window focus has been lost && activity is not in a paused state
    // Its a valid check because showing of notification panel
    // steals the focus from current activity's window, but does not 
    // 'pause' the activity
    if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {

        // Post a Runnable with some delay - currently set to 300 ms
        collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Use reflection to trigger a method from 'StatusBarManager'                

                Object statusBarService = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

                try {
                    statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Method collapseStatusBar = null;

                try {

                    // Prior to API 17, the method to call is 'collapse()'
                    // API 17 onwards, the method to call is `collapsePanels()`

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager .getMethod("collapsePanels");
                    } else {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager .getMethod("collapse");
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);

                try {
                    collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Check if the window focus has been returned
                // If it hasn't been returned, post this Runnable again
                // Currently, the delay is 100 ms. You can change this
                // value to suit your needs.
                if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {
                    collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100L);
                }

            }
        }, 300L);
    }   
}
```

Finally, override onPause() and onResume methods:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Activity's been paused      
    isPaused = true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Activity's been resumed
    isPaused = false;
}
```

Done!

NOTE: I used the 1st option when putting an app in kiosk mode, which doesn't show the notification panel at all.
On the other hand, the 2nd option works well, but it allows the notification panel to show up for a short time, and user can quickly click the settings icon on the top of the notification panel to quit the kiosk mode.

Hope this will help you.
Cheers!

Comment: Great detailed answer. However, when running the 1st option I'm getting  RuntimeException caused by: ---Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@38883eaa -- permission denied for this window type--- Any thoughts on how to make it work?

Comment: you need to give overlay permissions

Comment: @Royz can you share me the fixes you did on your comments.

Comment: Solution 1 won't work on android 10. It draws the overlay, but still behind the status bar

Comment: @DemetrioGuilardi same for me Option 1 not working at all in Android 10

Comment: Option 1 works for me up to Android 7 but from 8.1.0 I get `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@89fdb38 -- permission denied for window type 2010`. I have requested and been granted `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you refer Android AOSP, you'll see that there is a public method `public void disable(int what)` provided by StatusBarManager which takes FLAGs. I tried to reflect it, but was in vain!

The problem was the parameter type and `getMethod(String methodName)` usage, which failed, but instead when I used the correct parameter specification, I was able to pull it off.

So here's a reference of Android `AOSP 9.0r34` source `android/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/StatusBarManager.java`

```
...
...
...
public class StatusBarManager {

    public static final int DISABLE_EXPAND = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_EXPAND;
    public static final int DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ICONS = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ICONS;
    public static final int DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ALERTS
            = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ALERTS;
    @Deprecated
    public static final int DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_TICKER
            = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_TICKER;
    public static final int DISABLE_SYSTEM_INFO = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_SYSTEM_INFO;
    public static final int DISABLE_HOME = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_HOME;
    public static final int DISABLE_RECENT = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_RECENT;
    public static final int DISABLE_BACK = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_BACK;
    public static final int DISABLE_CLOCK = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_CLOCK;
    public static final int DISABLE_SEARCH = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_SEARCH;

    @Deprecated
    public static final int DISABLE_NAVIGATION = 
            View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_HOME | View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_RECENT;

    public static final int DISABLE_NONE = 0x00000000;

    public static final int DISABLE_MASK = DISABLE_EXPAND | DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ICONS
            | DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ALERTS | DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_TICKER
            | DISABLE_SYSTEM_INFO | DISABLE_RECENT | DISABLE_HOME | DISABLE_BACK | DISABLE_CLOCK
            | DISABLE_SEARCH;

...
...
...

    /**
     * Disable some features in the status bar.  Pass the bitwise-or of the DISABLE_* flags.
     * To re-enable everything, pass {@link #DISABLE_NONE}.
     */
    public void disable(int what) {
        try {
            final IStatusBarService svc = getService();
            if (svc != null) {
                svc.disable(what, mToken, mContext.getPackageName());
            }
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            throw ex.rethrowFromSystemServer();
        }
    }

...
...
...
```

So what I am doing is getting the right method, and then invoking the disable FLAGs on it.

Simply speaking anything like `View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_EXPAND` should have worked, but for some reason, even though in Android Studio I can see the code, and it is public inside `View` class, I cannot access it. However, I was able to use the actual HEX values. So finally, without much ado, Here's the solution:

But first, review the `View.java`'s FLAGS:

```
    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to make the status bar not expandable.  Unless you also
     * set {@link #STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ICONS}, new notifications will continue to show.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_EXPAND = 0x00010000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to hide notification icons and scrolling ticker text.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ICONS = 0x00020000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to disable incoming notification alerts.  This will not block
     * icons, but it will block sound, vibrating and other visual or aural notifications.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ALERTS = 0x00040000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to hide only the scrolling ticker.  Note that
     * {@link #STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_ICONS} implies
     * {@link #STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_TICKER}.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_TICKER = 0x00080000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to hide the center system info area.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_SYSTEM_INFO = 0x00100000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to hide only the home button.  Don't use this
     * unless you're a special part of the system UI (i.e., setup wizard, keyguard).
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_HOME = 0x00200000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to hide only the back button. Don't use this
     * unless you're a special part of the system UI (i.e., setup wizard, keyguard).
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_BACK = 0x00400000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to hide only the clock.  You might use this if your activity has
     * its own clock making the status bar's clock redundant.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_CLOCK = 0x00800000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to hide only the recent apps button. Don't use this
     * unless you're a special part of the system UI (i.e., setup wizard, keyguard).
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_RECENT = 0x01000000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to disable the global search gesture. Don't use this
     * unless you're a special part of the system UI (i.e., setup wizard, keyguard).
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_SEARCH = 0x02000000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to specify that the status bar is displayed in transient mode.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_TRANSIENT = 0x04000000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to specify that the navigation bar is displayed in transient mode.
     */
    public static final int NAVIGATION_BAR_TRANSIENT = 0x08000000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to specify that the hidden status bar would like to be shown.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_UNHIDE = 0x10000000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to specify that the hidden navigation bar would like to be shown.
     */
    public static final int NAVIGATION_BAR_UNHIDE = 0x20000000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to specify that the status bar is displayed in translucent mode.
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_TRANSLUCENT = 0x40000000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * NOTE: This flag may only be used in subtreeSystemUiVisibility. It is masked
     * out of the public fields to keep the undefined bits out of the developer's way.
     *
     * Flag to specify that the navigation bar is displayed in translucent mode.
     */
    public static final int NAVIGATION_BAR_TRANSLUCENT = 0x80000000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * Makes navigation bar transparent (but not the status bar).
     */
    public static final int NAVIGATION_BAR_TRANSPARENT = 0x00008000;

    /**
     * @hide
     *
     * Makes status bar transparent (but not the navigation bar).
     */
    public static final int STATUS_BAR_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000008;
```

NEXT, the actual solution: I used two flags, namely, `public static final int DISABLE_EXPAND = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_EXPAND;` & `public static final int DISABLE_RECENT = View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_RECENT;`, whose HEX you can find in `View.java`

```
    public static void disableStatusBar(Context context) {
        Log.d(Home.class.getCanonicalName(), "disableStatusBar: ");
        // Read from property or pass it in function, whatever works for you!
        boolean disable = SystemProperties.getBoolean(context, "supercool.status.bar.disable", true);
        Object statusBarService = context.getSystemService("statusbar");

        Class<?> statusBarManager = null;
        try {
            statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            try {
                final Method disable_statusBarFeatures = statusBarManager.getMethod("disable", int.class);
                try {
                    disable_statusBarFeatures.setAccessible(true);
                    if (disable) {
                        disable_statusBarFeatures.invoke(statusBarService, 0x00010000 | 0x00040000);
                    } else {
                        disable_statusBarFeatures.invoke(statusBarService, 0x00000000);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(Home.class.getCanonicalName(), "disableStatusBar: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Home.class.getCanonicalName(), "disableStatusBar: " + e.getMessage(), e);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Home.class.getCanonicalName(), "disableStatusBar: " + e.getMessage(), e);

        }
    }
```

Lastly, you'll need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />`, or else, it will `Throw` `InvocationTargetException` & `SecurityException`

I call this method in `onResume()` so, if I modify the property at runtime, I can Re-Enable the StatusBar back.

Comment: its giving me invocation target exception

Comment: Post your error or trace here @JasarOrion

Comment: This is the correct solution. Please note that this is only possible for system apps. Normal user apps will fail in the call to set the disable flags.

Comment: well done! I am developing a system app for a custom Android and it works for me. so no need to edit the Android system packages any more. I control the view of navigation button by this code. thanks.

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Working well for Android 11 system application