# Setting up permissions for "Permissions denied for this window type" error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-permissions

I need my application to enter in kiosk mode (disable all buttons). 
This application will be installed with all the phones (we work with the cellphone manufacturer).

**WHAT I NEED:**

I need to disable the top bar drag, I am looking tho capture all inputs and do nothing with them as suggestion in various places (ex. [How to disable status bar click and pull down in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969086/how-to-disable-status-bar-click-and-pull-down-in-android))

**WHAT I AM DOING:**

I am following that solution, checking for the android version and changing the layout parameters if necessary.

**MY PROBLEM:**

I am having the "permission denied for window type 2038" error that forces my application to close. This topic offered some light on my problem: [Android: Unable to add window. Permission denied for this window type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224452/android-unable-to-add-window-permission-denied-for-this-window-type)

However, I do not want to notify the user of the lock screen. I am working directly with the manufacturer so I should get the permissions that I want.

**MY QUESTION:**

How can I setup the necessary permissions to solve the problem described above?

Thank you very much!