# Flutter disable status bar

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am building a launcher app using Flutter and one of the business rules is to not allow the user to pull down the notifications drawer from the status bar. I tried using this code from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969086/how-to-disable-status-bar-click-and-pull-down-in-android) but its not working at all. Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried hiding the status bar using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` but users can view it when they pull down from the status bar area.

Answer (score -1):

Dealing with the same issue. Need to create a full immerse experience. From my research into the all I found was that SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]) is the best solution right now for flutter. I tinkered with the other solution I found but couldn't make it to work and some will have issue if you want to implement sliver.

Let me know if you find anything new.

Thanks

Comment: hi there. this doesn't answer the OP's question. would probably be better served as a comment to the OP.

Comment: @matias elgart It seems a reasonable answer since it does work on both Android and iOS.