# Android Prevent notification bar to be pulled down

Tags: android

i need to make a Kisk mode app.
Everihing is ok but i need to prevent or hide the notification top bar and prevent it to be pulled.

how to do that?

im using this tutorial:
https://www.andreasschrade.com/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

but when i active the first choice i canot touch in anywhere from my app and second choice its noting making anything.

i tryed to do it and nothing to:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
    // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable status bar click and pull down in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969086/how-to-disable-status-bar-click-and-pull-down-in-android)

Comment: i found this article but im trying to implement it with no success :( im new on android.

Comment: i tryed to use method 2 but i canot click in anywhere of my app. and method 1 dont make anything