# How can I make the status bar go back up after being pulled down on an android app?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, oncreate, android-statusbar

I've added the following code to my `onCreate` method:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);`
```

but when I then pull down the status bar, it doesn't go away again like I would like it to. I'm assuming that's because it's in the `onCreate` method, but what can I do to rectify this?

Comment: have a look on to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457730/preventing-status-bar-expansion