# Adb monkey testing fall out to other packages

Tags: java, android, testing, adb, monkey

I'm using the following command to test my android app
`pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb","-s", deviceId,"shell", "monkey -p" + packageName + " -v 5000");`

My problem is that when the adb monkey start to test then it open also system settings, audio player etc.
Is there any other solution for the adb monkey to stay only to specific package name?

Comment: that's what `-p` parameter is supposed to do - to limit the events to a specific package.

Comment: @AlexP. But it seems not to work because i have this -p in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To prevent monkey from opening settings, there was a question and an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349378/7407999

   I have searched the answer to the problem for many days, but only this answer solves the problem.
2. To prevent audio player, set "--pct-syskeys 0" in monkey options. See:
   https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html