# Event when display Dialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog

I have method to hidden status bar and navigation bar, I called success in Activity...but when I click settings to display dialog status bar and nav bar are displaying. I want to know event when display dialog to call method hidden status and nav bar. Thanks

Activity home
[image]

Settings Dialog
[image]

Comment: You can't really do this without effort.  There is no call that will hide status nav bar or nav bar without a bit of hacking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457730/preventing-status-bar-expansion/31349378#31349378

Comment: Thanks but I only hidden not disable it :(

Comment: I don't know a way to do that.

Comment: :(...........................